# SystemD doesn't automount folder in subdirectory of another mount, how to fix?

Tags: linux, systemd, automounting

I have local file server which exports two places over SMB: \media and \something

I want to have them mounted as /media/MEDIA (\media export) and /media/MEDIA/something (\something).

To do it I created two .mount units:

```
=# cat /etc/systemd/system/media-MEDIA.mount
[Mount]
What=//media.server/Media/
Where=/media/MEDIA
Type=cifs
Options=guest,user
```

and

```
=# cat /etc/systemd/system/media-MEDIA-something.mount
[Mount]
What=//media.server/something/
Where=/media/MEDIA/something
Type=cifs
Options=guest,user
```

Reloaded systemctl, and verified that it all works.

But then I wanted to get them automounted on reboot. So made automount units:

```
=# cat /etc/systemd/system/media-MEDIA.automount
[Unit]
Requires=remote-fs-pre.target
After=remote-fs-pre.target

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

and

```
=# cat /etc/systemd/system/media-MEDIA-something.automount
[Unit]
Requires=remote-fs-pre.target
After=remote-fs-pre.target media-MEDIA.automount

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

After reload/reboot - only /media/MEDIA is mounted. To mount "something" I have to manually:

```
=$ sudo systemctl start media-MEDIA-something.mount
```

/media/MEDIA, after being mounted, does contain directory "something".

Automounts are enabled, but automount for "something" is broken:

```
=# systemctl status media-MEDIA-something.automount
○ media-MEDIA-something.automount
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/media-MEDIA-something.automount; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
   Triggers: ● media-MEDIA-something.mount
      Where: /media/MEDIA/something

Nov 18 14:31:42 thebox systemd[1]: Dependency failed for media-MEDIA-something.automount.
Nov 18 14:31:42 thebox systemd[1]: media-MEDIA-something.automount: Job media-MEDIA-something.automount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

What am I missing? What did I screw up?